# HitTestBehavior.translucent not permitting targets behind it to also receive events

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Minimal reproducible code**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => print('Black'),
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => print('White'),
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

[Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/HitTestBehavior-class.html) says:

> `HitTestBehavior.translucent`: Translucent targets both receive events within their bounds and permit targets visually behind them to also receive events.

As I'm using `HitTestBehavior.translucent` for my white container (second `GestureDetector`) but then why clicking on it doesn't print both `White` and `Black`?

**PS:** I am not looking for a way to pass the touch events to the first child, it can easily be done using `IgnorePointer`.

Comment: I made a small research you may need to follow this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450#issuecomment-601268747

Comment: As @esentis mentioned in the referenced Github discussion, There is an "Arena" and only one widget will be able to listen to this event but luckily this behavior is overridable. See at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77171535/13898059

Answer (score 0):

`onTap` didn't work for me, I use `onTapDown` instead.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => print('Black'),
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => print('White'),
          onTapDown: (_) { // this one 
            debugPrint("on White pan down");
          },
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18450#issuecomment-397372078

> `translucent` means that the hit testing will traverse below. However, if both widgets are listening for the same gesture, in this case Tap, only one will "win". You can tell that both are getting the pointers though by listening to `onTapDown` instead of `onTap`.