# Flutter GestureDetector InAppWebView Sliding

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector, flutter-inappwebview

I hope the page can slide up, down, left and right, and the outer GestureDetector can receive the event of horizontal sliding when the page cannot slide left and right. What should I do?
I hope the page can slide up, down, left and right, and the outer GestureDetector can receive the event of horizontal sliding when the page cannot slide left and right. What should I do?
I hope the page can slide up, down, left and right, and the outer GestureDetector can receive the event of horizontal sliding when the page cannot slide left and right. What should I do?

```dart
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestWidget> createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  late Offset downPos;

  //滑动距离
  double slidingDistance = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          InAppWebView(
            initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
              url: Uri.parse('http://www.baidu.com'),
            ),
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
              ),
            ),
            onLoadStart: (controller, url) {},
            shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
              if (await _openThirdApp(navigationAction)) {
                return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
              }
              return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
            },
            onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {},
            onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {},
            onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {},
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(
                slidingDistance - 200.w,
                0,
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: 200.w,
                height: 50.h,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onHorizontalDragStart: (d) {
        downPos = d.localPosition;
      },
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (d) {
        final move = d.localPosition;
        setState(() {
          slidingDistance = (downPos.dx - move.dx).abs();
        });
      },
      onHorizontalDragEnd: (d) {
        setState(() {
          slidingDistance = 0;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  //判断调起第三方app
  Future<bool> _openThirdApp(
    NavigationAction navigationAction,
  ) async {
    final uri = navigationAction.request.url!;
    if (!['http', 'https', 'file', 'chrome', 'data', 'javascript', 'about']
        .contains(uri.scheme)) {
      if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
        await launchUrl(
          uri,
        );
      }

      return Future.value(true);
    }
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There two steps to handle such case:

1. Tell the `InAppWebView` to listen for gestures

- Use this property inside `InAppWebView`

```
gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
  Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
    () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
  ),
  Factory<HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer>(
    () => HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer(),
  ),
},
```

2. Ovrride functionality of so-called "Arena" gesture detector mechanism to accept multiple listeners.

- Inside `allow_multiple_gestures.dart`.

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

// Custom Gesture Recognizer.
// rejectGesture() is overridden. When a gesture is rejected, this is the function that is called. By default, it disposes of the
// Recognizer and runs clean up. However we modified it so that instead the Recognizer is disposed of, it is actually manually added.
// The result is instead you have one Recognizer winning the Arena, you have two. It is a win-win.
class AllowMultipleHorizontalDrag extends HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer {
  @override
  void rejectGesture(int pointer) {
    acceptGesture(pointer);
  }

}

class AllowMultipleDoubleTap extends DoubleTapGestureRecognizer {
  @override
  void rejectGesture(int pointer) {
    acceptGesture(pointer);
  }
}
```

- Finally, Replace your `GestureDetector` with `RawGestureDetector` in order to be able to customize the gesture we use and then use the gestures we overrode earlier.

```
RawGestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  gestures: {
    AllowMultipleHorizontalDrag:
        GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
            AllowMultipleHorizontalDrag>(
      () => AllowMultipleHorizontalDrag(),
      (AllowMultipleHorizontalDrag instance) {
        instance.onEnd = (details) async {
          // logic 
        };
      },
    ),
    AllowMultipleDoubleTap: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
        AllowMultipleDoubleTap>(
      () => AllowMultipleDoubleTap(),
      (AllowMultipleDoubleTap instance) {
        instance.onDoubleTap =
            () => print('Your logic');
      },
    )
  },
  child: InAppWebView(
```

Now you should be able to get gestures in both widgets.

For clarity read below articles :

[Solution guide](https://medium.com/koahealth/combining-multiple-gesturedetectors-in-flutter-26d899d008b2)

[Deep dive](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-deep-dive-gestures-c16203b3434f)