# GestureDetector not working with InAppWebView

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector, flutter-inappwebview

I have a `GestureDetector` and It's child is `InAppWebView`, I am using `onHorizontalDragEnd` property of `GestureDetector`, Down below I indicate that I am using `gestureRecognizers` of `InAppWebView`.

Code:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ColorsTheme.of(context).screenBackground,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: PresenterHooks(
          presenter: presenter,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) async {
                  final webViewController = state.webviewController!;

                  if (details.primaryVelocity! < 0 - primaryVelocity &&
                      (await webViewController.canGoForward())) {
                    webViewController.goForward();
                  }

                  if (details.primaryVelocity! > primaryVelocity &&
                      (await webViewController.canGoBack())) {
                    webViewController.goBack();
                  }

                  if (details.primaryVelocity! > primaryVelocity &&
                      !(await webViewController.canGoBack())) {
                    if (BottomFlowDialog.maybeOf(context) != null) {
                      BottomFlowDialog.of(context).close();
                    }
                  }
                },
                onDoubleTap: () => state.webviewController!.reload(),
                child: InAppWebView(
                  ...
                  gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
                    Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer(),
                    ),
                    Factory<HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer(),
                    ),
                    Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                    ),
                  },
                  ...
                ),
              ),
              if (state.progress != 100)
                LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: state.progress / 100,
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The expected behavior is that both `GestureDetector` & `InAppWebView` listen to the drag event and get that, But now only `InAppWebView` is getting the events, And `GestureDetector` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the issue with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77171535/13898059) approach more details are also provided at the end of the answer.